# Formatting Data to Output to Excel

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a beginner at Python. I know that right now this is spaghetti code. Please ignore my Barbaric use of Regex to format some of the data, that will be for my next post.

However, I am attempting to scrape Texas Hold 'Em hand rankings from a website and output them to an Excel file so that they can be easily searched using ctrl F.

The table on the website isn't coded as a  in HTML so I decided to use BeautifulSoup to scrape this information.

So far I have managed to convert the data to a list from a string. When I export this to Excel it puts the entire row in the same column cell, when it should be separated by cards, probablility of winning, etc row by row..

How can I format this data to have each row display in it's own cell? I have an idea to use a for loop to iterate through the list of hands and all of their information but I don't know how I can differentiate between different headers such as Cards, Probability of Win, etc. I have so far used Regex to format the data so that it can be easily split, which is the separate variable.

The website table is a good example of how I would like the data to display in Excel: https://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/6-player-game/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import xlsxwriter

url = "https://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/6-player-game/"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

def getContent():
    table_data = soup.find(class_ = "box-content has-data").get_text()

    handRegex1 = re.sub("Pair of ", "", table_data)
    handRegex2 = re.sub("'", "", handRegex1)
    handRegex3 = re.sub("/", "", handRegex2)
    handRegex4 = re.sub(" suited", "s", handRegex3)
    handRegex5 = re.sub(" unsuited", "o", handRegex4)
    handRegex6 = re.sub("""
    """, " ", handRegex5)
    handRegex7 = re.sub("\n", " ", handRegex6)
    handRegex8 = re.sub("\s\s\s", ",", handRegex7)
    separate = handRegex8.split(",")
    print(handRegex7)

    #using handRegex7 we can add each word to an individual cell. We have to separate the headers and sort those, the actual data should be easy to seperate by space charecter.

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/Users/colivart/Excel_Files/Texas_Hold_Em_6.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    """
    We can use for loop to iterate through format variable.
    This will allow us to add each hand
    and it's values one by one.
    """


    worksheet.write_column('A1', format)

    workbook.close()

getContent()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `requests` and `pandas` to get what you want?

Here's how:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

page = requests.get("https://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/6-player-game/").text
df = pd.read_html(page, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
print(tabulate(df, showindex=False))
df.to_csv("poker_hands.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

And this is what you get (along with a `.csv` file that you can import to Excel):

```
------------  ------------------  -----------  --------------  -----------  --------------------
Cards         Probability of Win  Average Win  Expected Value  Probability  Additive Probability
Pair of A's   49.51%              5.96         1.9508          0.45%        0.45%
Pair of K's   43.32%              5.95         1.5775          0.45%        0.90%
Pair of Q's   38.3%               5.93         1.2729          0.45%        1.36%
Pair of J's   34.05%              5.92         1.0142          0.45%        1.81%
A/K suited    32.15%              5.8          0.8641          0.30%        2.11%
Pair of T's   30.44%              5.89         0.7944          0.45%        2.56%
A/Q suited    30.56%              5.76         0.7589          0.30%        2.87%
K/Q suited    29.55%              5.76         0.7015          0.30%        3.17%
A/J suited    29.28%              5.71         0.6723          0.30%        3.47%
A/K unsuited  28.96%              5.77         0.6704          0.90%        4.37%
K/J suited    28.28%              5.72         0.6167          0.30%        4.68%
A/T suited    28.27%              5.67         0.6021          0.30%        4.98%
Pair of 9's   27.11%              5.89         0.5978          0.45%        5.43%
Q/J suited    27.57%              5.71         0.5737          0.30%        5.73%
A/Q unsuited  27.21%              5.71         0.555           0.90%        6.64%
K/T suited    27.32%              5.68         0.5506          0.30%        6.94%
Q/T suited    26.64%              5.67         0.5101          0.30%        7.24%
K/Q unsuited  26.28%              5.72         0.5028          0.90%        8.14%
J/T suited    26.33%              5.66         0.4904          0.30%        8.45%
A/J unsuited  25.79%              5.66         0.4597          0.90%        9.35%
A/9 suited    25.75%              5.62         0.4474          0.30%        9.65%
Pair of 8's   24.51%              5.88         0.4416          0.45%        10.11%
K/J unsuited  24.88%              5.67         0.4097          0.90%        11.01%
K/9 suited    24.73%              5.64         0.3946          0.30%        11.31%
A/8 suited    24.98%              5.58         0.3933          0.30%        11.61%
A/T unsuited  24.66%              5.6          0.3817          0.90%        12.52%
Q/J unsuited  24.26%              5.66         0.3721          0.90%        13.42%
Q/9 suited    24.07%              5.64         0.3565          0.30%        13.73%
A/7 suited    24.27%              5.54         0.3444          0.30%        14.03%
T/9 suited    23.9%               5.62         0.3432          0.30%        14.33%
J/9 suited    23.82%              5.63         0.3408          0.30%        14.63%
K/T unsuited  23.8%               5.61         0.3356          0.90%        15.54%
A/5 suited    24.19%              5.5          0.3309          0.30%        15.84%
Pair of 7's   22.35%              5.87         0.3116          0.45%        16.29%
Q/T unsuited  23.2%               5.61         0.3006          0.90%        17.19%
A/4 suited    23.63%              5.5          0.3002          0.30%        17.5%
A/6 suited    23.5%               5.51         0.2954          0.30%        17.8%
J/T unsuited  23.03%              5.6          0.2895          0.90%        18.7%
K/8 suited    22.97%              5.58         0.283           0.30%        19%
A/3 suited    23.05%              5.51         0.2705          0.30%        19.31%
Q/8 suited    22.24%              5.59         0.2436          0.30%        19.61%
K/7 suited    22.37%              5.55         0.2406          0.30%        19.91%
A/2 suited    22.39%              5.52         0.2357          0.30%        20.21%
T/8 suited    22.12%              5.58         0.2345          0.30%        20.51%
J/8 suited    22.01%              5.59         0.2298          0.30%        20.81%
9/8 suited    21.72%              5.6          0.2165          0.30%        21.12%
A/9 unsuited  21.93%              5.53         0.2136          0.90%        22.02%
Pair of 6's   20.59%              5.85         0.2054          0.45%        22.47%
K/6 suited    21.75%              5.52         0.1996          0.30%        22.78%
K/5 suited    21.29%              5.49         0.1692          0.30%        23.08%
K/9 unsuited  20.98%              5.56         0.1659          0.90%        23.98%
A/8 unsuited  21.07%              5.47         0.1533          0.90%        24.89%
Q/7 suited    20.65%              5.54         0.1434          0.30%        25.19%
K/4 suited    20.75%              5.5          0.1406          0.30%        25.49%
8/7 suited    20.39%              5.57         0.1367          0.30%        25.79%
Q/9 unsuited  20.41%              5.55         0.1334          0.90%        26.7%
T/7 suited    20.46%              5.54         0.1333          0.30%        27%
T/9 unsuited  20.44%              5.54         0.1322          0.90%        27.9%
9/7 suited    20.30%              5.57         0.1299          0.30%        28.21%
J/7 suited    20.38%              5.54         0.1293          0.30%        28.51%
J/9 unsuited  20.28%              5.55         0.1248          0.90%        29.41%
K/3 suited    20.25%              5.51         0.1154          0.30%        29.71%
Pair of 5's   19.05%              5.84         0.1118          0.45%        30.17%
Q/6 suited    20.19%              5.5          0.1109          0.30%        30.47%
A/7 unsuited  20.25%              5.42         0.0981          0.90%        31.37%
K/2 suited    19.76%              5.52         0.0909          0.30%        31.67%
A/5 unsuited  20.15%              5.37         0.083           0.90%        32.58%
Q/5 suited    19.72%              5.48         0.0806          0.30%        32.88%
7/6 suited    19.31%              5.56         0.0736          0.30%        33.18%
8/6 suited    19.11%              5.54         0.059           0.30%        33.48%
Q/4 suited    19.22%              5.49         0.0547          0.30%        33.79%
A/4 unsuited  19.51%              5.37         0.0484          0.90%        34.69%
A/6 unsuited  19.43%              5.38         0.0458          0.90%        35.6%
K/8 unsuited  19.04%              5.48         0.043           0.90%        36.5%
T/6 suited    18.95%              5.49         0.0407          0.30%        36.8%
9/6 suited    18.82%              5.53         0.0402          0.30%        37.1%
J/6 suited    18.92%              5.49         0.038           0.30%        37.41%
Pair of 4's   17.76%              5.84         0.0369          0.45%        37.86%
Q/3 suited    18.69%              5.5          0.0281          0.30%        38.16%
6/5 suited    18.45%              5.55         0.0233          0.30%        38.46%
A/3 unsuited  18.87%              5.38         0.0148          0.90%        39.37%
T/8 unsuited  18.5%               5.48         0.0138          0.90%        40.27%
J/5 suited    18.56%              5.46         0.0131          0.30%        40.57%
Q/8 unsuited  18.43%              5.48         0.0104          0.90%        41.48%
Q/2 suited    18.25%              5.52         0.0063          0.30%        41.78%
J/8 unsuited  18.31%              5.48         0.004           0.90%        42.68%
7/5 suited    18.1%               5.53         0.0007          0.30%        42.99%
9/8 unsuited  18.14%              5.5          -0.0013         0.90%        43.89%
K/7 unsuited  18.38%              5.42         -0.0036         0.90%        44.8%
5/4 suited    17.82%              5.54         -0.0125         0.30%        45.1%
J/4 suited    18.03%              5.47         -0.0139         0.30%        45.4%
A/2 unsuited  18.15%              5.38         -0.0235         0.90%        46.3%
8/5 suited    17.73%              5.5          -0.0244         0.30%        46.61%
Pair of 3's   16.69%              5.85         -0.0245         0.45%        47.06%
J/3 suited    17.57%              5.48         -0.0365         0.30%        47.36%
T/5 suited    17.62%              5.44         -0.041          0.30%        47.66%
9/5 suited    17.41%              5.48         -0.0458         0.30%        47.96%
K/6 unsuited  17.72%              5.38         -0.047          0.90%        48.87%
6/4 suited    17.17%              5.54         -0.0484         0.30%        49.17%
J/2 suited    17.11%              5.5          -0.0589         0.30%        49.47%
T/4 suited    17.19%              5.44         -0.0643         0.30%        49.77%
Pair of 2's   15.87%              5.85         -0.0708         0.45%        50.23%
7/4 suited    16.66%              5.52         -0.0809         0.30%        50.53%
5/3 suited    16.59%              5.54         -0.081          0.30%        50.83%
K/5 unsuited  17.18%              5.34         -0.0829         0.90%        51.73%
8/7 unsuited  16.76%              5.47         -0.0841         0.90%        52.64%
T/3 suited    16.72%              5.46         -0.0871         0.30%        52.94%
9/7 unsuited  16.61%              5.45         -0.0953         0.90%        53.85%
T/7 unsuited  16.71%              5.41         -0.0962         0.90%        54.75%
Q/7 unsuited  16.7%               5.4          -0.098          0.90%        55.66%
J/7 unsuited  16.51%              5.41         -0.1073         0.90%        56.56%
8/4 suited    16.25%              5.49         -0.1085         0.30%        56.86%
T/2 suited    16.27%              5.48         -0.1089         0.30%        57.16%
K/4 unsuited  16.59%              5.34         -0.114          0.90%        58.07%
4/3 suited    15.9%               5.56         -0.1162         0.30%        58.37%
9/4 suited    16.05%              5.46         -0.1237         0.30%        58.67%
6/3 suited    15.77%              5.54         -0.127          0.30%        58.97%
Q/6 unsuited  16.17%              5.35         -0.135          0.90%        59.88%
K/3 unsuited  16.03%              5.35         -0.142          0.90%        60.78%
9/3 suited    15.67%              5.47         -0.143          0.30%        61.09%
7/6 unsuited  15.62%              5.43         -0.1512         0.90%        61.99%
5/2 suited    15.19%              5.53         -0.1593         0.30%        62.29%
7/3 suited    15.25%              5.51         -0.1605         0.30%        62.59%
9/2 suited    15.22%              5.49         -0.1644         0.30%        62.9%
Q/5 unsuited  15.66%              5.31         -0.1685         0.90%        63.8%
K/2 unsuited  15.49%              5.36         -0.1695         0.90%        64.71%
8/6 unsuited  15.35%              5.41         -0.1698         0.90%        65.61%
8/3 suited    14.94%              5.47         -0.1832         0.30%        65.91%
4/2 suited    14.68%              5.56         -0.1836         0.30%        66.21%
9/6 unsuited  15%                 5.38         -0.193          0.90%        67.12%
T/6 unsuited  15.06%              5.33         -0.1972         0.90%        68.02%
Q/4 unsuited  15.08%              5.31         -0.1987         0.90%        68.93%
8/2 suited    14.58%              5.49         -0.2            0.30%        69.23%
6/5 unsuited  14.71%              5.41         -0.2045         0.90%        70.14%
J/6 unsuited  14.94%              5.32         -0.2053         0.90%        71.04%
6/2 suited    14.37%              5.53         -0.2056         0.30%        71.34%
3/2 suited    14.02%              5.58         -0.2171         0.30%        71.64%
Q/3 unsuited  14.52%              5.33         -0.2267         0.90%        72.55%
7/5 unsuited  14.34%              5.38         -0.2289         0.90%        73.45%
7/2 suited    13.97%              5.49         -0.2331         0.30%        73.76%
J/5 unsuited  14.53%              5.27         -0.2339         0.90%        74.66%
5/4 unsuited  14.05%              5.39         -0.2418         0.90%        75.57%
Q/2 unsuited  14%                 5.34         -0.2523         0.90%        76.47%
8/5 unsuited  13.87%              5.34         -0.2595         0.90%        77.38%
J/4 unsuited  13.96%              5.28         -0.2632         0.90%        78.28%
6/4 unsuited  13.34%              5.39         -0.2814         0.90%        79.19%
9/5 unsuited  13.48%              5.3          -0.2859         0.90%        80.09%
T/5 unsuited  13.63%              5.24         -0.2859         0.90%        81%
J/3 unsuited  13.42%              5.29         -0.2898         0.90%        81.9%
T/4 unsuited  13.16%              5.23         -0.3113         0.90%        82.81%
J/2 unsuited  12.92%              5.3          -0.3147         0.90%        83.71%
5/3 unsuited  12.71%              5.38         -0.3167         0.90%        84.62%
7/4 unsuited  12.78%              5.34         -0.3175         0.90%        85.52%
T/3 unsuited  12.62%              5.25         -0.3377         0.90%        86.43%
8/4 unsuited  12.29%              5.29         -0.35           0.90%        87.33%
4/3 unsuited  11.99%              5.39         -0.3537         0.90%        88.24%
T/2 unsuited  12.12%              5.26         -0.3623         0.90%        89.14%
6/3 unsuited  11.82%              5.35         -0.3672         0.90%        90.05%
9/4 unsuited  12.01%              5.24         -0.371          0.90%        90.95%
9/3 unsuited  11.58%              5.25         -0.3927         0.90%        91.86%
5/2 unsuited  11.23%              5.34         -0.3998         0.90%        92.76%
7/3 unsuited  11.24%              5.3          -0.4046         0.90%        93.67%
9/2 unsuited  11.08%              5.26         -0.417          0.90%        94.57%
4/2 unsuited  10.67%              5.37         -0.4267         0.90%        95.48%
8/3 unsuited  10.86%              5.23         -0.4314         0.90%        96.38%
6/2 unsuited  10.32%              5.31         -0.4519         0.90%        97.29%
8/2 unsuited  10.45%              5.24         -0.4522         0.90%        98.19%
3/2 unsuited  9.98%               5.39         -0.462          0.90%        99.1%
7/2 unsuited  9.87%               5.24         -0.4833         0.90%        100%
Total         18.14%              5.51         0               100%         0%
------------  ------------------  -----------  --------------  -----------  --------------------
```

And here's what inside the `.csv` file:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why but I was thinking that pandas could only be used when the data was formatted as a <table> in HTML code, that's awesome! Could I still use Regex to edit the names of the hands when using a data frame?

Comment: Sure you can. And if you find my answer useful please upvote and/or accept it. There's tick next to the answer. Thanks! Have fun coding!

Comment: Will do, it's telling me one more minute before I can accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to separate the values by ; and \n since excel files typically are comma-separated.

so when you retrieve your data and cleans it you have the values
Cards;Probability;Win\n
card1;probability1;win1\n
card2;probability2;win2\n

etc.